# How to build a data frame where one column adds onto the other in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I'd like to create a randomized data frame in R where the values of the 2nd column = 1st column + number and the next value of the 1st column = 2nd column + number

It would look something like this:

[image: Data frame example]

I've tried doing this:

```
Sal = rnorm(150,mean=18,sd=1.7)
H2O = Sal + 0.2358
d = data.frame(Sal = rep(Sal,1), H2O = rep(H2O,1))
df = d[order(d$Sal,d$H2O),]
df
```

But it doesn't really work since the next number doesn't "build" upon the previous number.

How could I do this? Should I use a loop instead? My R experience is fairly limited (as you can probably tell)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the randomness supposed to come from? If `number = 0.2358` is a constant, all other values are determined by the starting value.

Comment: @IanCampbell The randomness comes from the values on Column 1 and 2 (Would be Salt and H2O)

It would be cool if the number (0.2358) could also be a randomized one (interval would be 0.100 to 0.350), but I'm not sure how to do that just yet

Comment: But in your example, 14.231 looks random, but 14.872 is not random, it is `14.231 + 2*number`. Your code says that you want to start with 150 random values, but your explanation says you want to start with 1 random value and build 150 values off of it.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, that would be it! :) The numbers I used for the table was just as an example (I didn't add the 0.2358 on them, I just invented random numbers for the example). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Assuming `Sal = rnorm(1, mean=18, sd=1.7)` and `Const <- 0.2358` is this what you want? `Table <- matrix(Sal + 0:149 * Const, 75, 2, byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you question, looking at the desired output data.frame, if you focus on values from left-to-right and top-to-bottom, you will see that increment with respect to the first value as the reference can be written as

```
c(0,1,2,3,....,2*nr-1)*number
```

where `nr` is the number of rows of your desired output. In this since, the only thing you need to do is to create the sequence as the increments and add them up to the initial value.

---

You can try the code below

```
set.seed(1)
Sal <- rnorm(1, mean = 18, sd = 1.7)
number <- 0.2358
nr <- 10
df <- setNames(
  data.frame(
    matrix(Sal + (seq(2 * nr) - 1) * number,
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE
    )
  ),
  c("Sal", "H2O")
)
```

which gives

```
> df
        Sal      H2O
1  16.93503 17.17083
2  17.40663 17.64243
3  17.87823 18.11403
4  18.34983 18.58563
5  18.82143 19.05723
6  19.29303 19.52883
7  19.76463 20.00043
8  20.23623 20.47203
9  20.70783 20.94363
10 21.17943 21.41523
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `cumsum` is what you are looking for (and then filling the rows of your data frame):

```
set.seed(42)
n_rows <- 5
rnd_numbers <- rnorm(n_rows * 2, mean = 18, sd = 17)
entries <- cumsum(rnd_numbers)
df <- data.frame(matrix(entries, nrow = n_rows, byrow = T))
colnames(df) <- c('Sal', 'H20')
df

        Sal       H20
1  41.30629  49.70642
2  73.87961 102.63827
3 127.51083 143.70672
4 187.40259 203.79339
5 256.10659 273.04045
```

You can check that the result follows the structure you described above by having a look at the underlying random numbers:

```
rnd_numbers
[1] 41.306294  8.400131 24.173183 28.758664 24.872561 16.195883
[7] 43.695874 16.390796 52.313203 16.933860
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `Reduce`:

```
set.seed(123)
Start <- rnorm(1,14,1)
Values <- Reduce(`+`,rnorm(19, 0.25, 0.125),init = Start, accumulate = TRUE)
Matrix <- matrix(Values, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
Result <- setNames(as.data.frame(Matrix),c("Salt","H2O"))
Result       
       Salt      H2O
1  13.43952 13.66075
2  14.10559 14.36440
3  14.63057 15.09495
4  15.40256 15.49443
5  15.65857 15.85287
6  16.25588 16.55085
7  16.85095 17.11478
8  17.29530 17.76867
9  18.08090 18.08507
10 18.42274 18.61364
```

`Reduce`'s first argument is a function with two arguments, in our case `+`. We set `init =` to be the starting value, and then a random value generated by `rnorm` is added. That new value is used as the starting value for the next number. We use `accumulate = TRUE` to keep all the values.

From here, we can use `matrix()`, to change the vector of values into a `2 x n` matrix. Then we can convert to data.frame and add the column names.

Comment: That's it Ian! Thank you so much! :) I also appreciate the brief explanation of the code!

Comment: could you set a seed